# Is there easier way to unwrap this cube?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I'm really newbie with blender

I want to make this cube's UV properly with a single unwrap.

[image]

So, I marked seams like this

[image]

But this looks really weird
What i expect is just like this

[image]

Maybe i'm doing wrong with mark seam..

Is there any easier way to unwrap this cube properly?

Or It must be needed additional align work by hand?

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distortion might come from a setting, but I would also correct the seams. At first, I would set the seams inside the hole a little different. The way you have it, the unwrapping results in the top area having four flaps that would be overlapping if you simply fold them up in a 90° angle to have all rectangular UVs. Instead, I would suggest you set the seams of the side flaps on the top edge, so that the long flaps belong to the top area, the short flaps to the bottom area:

[image: change seams]

If you now unwrap, the UVs might still look a little distorted. This could be because the default options in the *Unwrap* menu have *Fill Holes* enabled. If you disable it, all should look fine:

[image: fill holes]

Comment: Oh God!!!! I will give you my deepest thanks.. This is Perfect.